# Prevent sssd from using ldap to authenticate or id specific users for chef

Tags: ldap, chef, sssd

I'm trying to use chef to add/modify a few local user accounts.  For whatever reason there are duplicate accounts in LDAP.  Since the system uses sssd/pam/ldap, it sees the user as existing, but is unable to modify them because they are not in /etc/passwd.

Is there a way to completely bypass the ldap accounts so that they do not id?  Then Chef will create them properly.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option in the ldap configuration to ignore ldap lookups for certain user ids. In

/etc/ldap.conf

```
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers root,ldap,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radvd,tomcat,radiusd,news,mailman
```

There is also this configuration value in the sssd config file

> filter_users, filter_groups (string) Exclude certain users from being
>   fetched from the sss NSS database. This is particularly useful for
>   system accounts. This option can also be set per-domain or include
>   fully-qualified names to filter only users from the particular domain.
>   Default: root